# Dynamic grid-template-rows based on :has()?

Tags: css, sass, modal-dialog

So I'm building a modal component with CSS and I'm thinking if there's any way to build the structure based on what's present in the modal.

The basic code might look something like this:

```css
.modal-inner {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows:
      [header] auto
      [content] 1fr
      [footer] auto;
    row-gap: 1rem;
}
```

But what happens if there's no header or footer present? The rows will still be generated, with a `1rem` gap at the start/end.

My current solution is to use CSS variables and check if the header and/or footer is present, like this:

```css
.modal-inner {
    --header-row: [header] auto;
    --content-row: [content] 1fr;
    --footer-row: [footer] auto;
    
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows:
        var(--header-row)
        var(--content-row)
        var(--footer-row);
    row-gap: 1rem;

    &:not(:has(.modal-header)) {
        grid-template-rows:
            var(--content-row)
            var(--footer-row);
    }

    &:not(:has(.modal-footer)) {
        grid-template-rows:
            var(--header-row)
            var(--content-row);

        &:not(:has(.modal-header)) {
            grid-template-rows: var(--content-row);
        }
    }
}
```

I bet there's more clever ways to solve this, and I'm eager to hear your proposals!

Comment: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/modern-layouts-using-css-grid